# Does the order of taking the mean across dimensions of a tensor matter?

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, means

Given a tensor of data with the shape $(a, b, c)$, I want to aggregate this tensor such that I have a shape of $(a,)$. Now my question is, does it matter whether I first take the mean across dimension $b$ and then $c$, or first $c$ and then $b$, or if I first reshape the tensor into $(a, b \cdot c)$ and then take the mean across the 2nd dimension.

I went through a toy example with 2 dimensions. My tensor:

\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d \\
e & f
\end{bmatrix}

First, the average across the first dimension:

$\frac{1}{3} \left(\frac{a+b}{2} + \frac{c+d}{2} + \frac{e+f}{2}\right) = \left(\frac{a+b+c+d+e+f}{6}\right)$

Average across the second dimension:

$\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{a+c+e}{3} + \frac{b+d+f}{3}\right) = \left(\frac{a+b+c+d+e+f}{6}\right)$

Both appear to be equal, as well as equal to first reshaping the data and then averaging.
Is this generally the case, or just for this toy example?

Comment: This question becomes fairly trivial if you forget about tensors and put your data into a linear order. Then take averages of sub-averages. You may want to use induction.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be any set partitioned into $n \geq 1$ equal cardinality parts
$$ X = X_1 \sqcup \cdots \sqcup X_n,$$
each of size $k = |X| / n$. Let $m_1, \ldots, m_n$ be the means
$$ m_i = \frac{1}{k}\sum_{x \in X_i} x,$$
then we have that
$$ \frac{1}{n}(m_1 + \cdots + m_m) = \frac{1}{nk}\sum_{x \in X} x,$$
which is the mean of $X$ since $nk = |X|$.

You should be able to iterate this argument to show that if you repeatedly perform operations like this, the total mean at the end will be correct. The key thing is that the partitions $X_i$ are of equal size (which will always happen for your tensors).

Comment: The condition that the partitions have to be of equal size can be relaxed
when one weights the average of averages properly:
$$
\frac{X_1+X_2+X_3}{3}=\frac{\overbrace{\frac{X_1+X_2}{2}+\frac{X_1+X_2}{2}}^{\text{counting twice}}+\overbrace{X_3}^{\text{once}}}{3}\,.
$$

Comment: @KurtG. - does this ever happen for the kind of averages the original poster is asking about?

Comment: Of course it does not. To tell OP that equal partitions are a key thing does however not really simplify that trivial matter. Imho OPs should be given just enough hints to be able to take full control.